# How can i receive the data that what i checked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, position

I want to get my cheked data that what i checked 
the problem is i'm using expandable layout 
and i don't know how to i  receive the real data info values items 
how can i do receive the data from my model?

This is my CheckedActivity

```
package com.example.together.Activities.GoodbyePet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.together.Model.SubCategoryItem;
import com.example.together.R;

public class CheckedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem;

    private TextView tvParent, tvChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checked);

        tvParent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
        tvChild = findViewById(R.id.child);

        for (int i = 0; i < MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.parentItems.size(); i++ ){

            String isChecked = MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.parentItems.get(i).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED);

            if (isChecked.equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE))
            {
                tvParent.setText(tvParent.getText() + MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.parentItems.get(i).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME));
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.childItems.get(i).size(); j++ ){

                String isChildChecked = MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.childItems.get(i).get(j).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED);

                if (isChildChecked.equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE))
                {
                    tvChild.setText(tvChild.getText() +" , " + MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.parentItems.get(i).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME) + " "+(j+1));
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my ConstantManager

```
package com.example.together.Activities.GoodbyePet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ConstantManager {

    public static final String CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE = "YES";
    public static final String CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE = "NO";

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems = new ArrayList<>();


    public class Parameter {
        public static final String IS_CHECKED = "is_checked";
        public static final String SUB_CATEGORY_NAME = "sub_category_name";
        public static final String SUB_CATEGORY_PRICE = "sub_category_price";
        public static final String CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
        public static final String CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
        public static final String SUB_ID = "sub_id";
        public static final String SUB_CATEGORY_IMAGE = "sub_category_image";

    }
}
```

This is my CategoryExpandableAdapter

```
package com.example.together.Activities.GoodbyePet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.together.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.example.together.Fragment.TabFragment1;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


/**
 * Created by zerones on 04-Oct-17.
 */

public class MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems;
    //    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> childItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private FragmentActivity activity;
    private HashMap<String, String> child;
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean isFromMyCategoriesFragment;

    public MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parentItems,
                                             ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childItems, boolean isFromMyCategoriesFragment) {

        this.parentItems = parentItems;
        this.childItems = childItems;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.isFromMyCategoriesFragment = isFromMyCategoriesFragment;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return (childItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
         final ViewHolderParent viewHolderParent;
        if (convertView == null) {

            if(isFromMyCategoriesFragment) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout_my_categories, null);
            }else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_layout_choose_categories, null);
            }
            viewHolderParent = new ViewHolderParent();


            viewHolderParent.tvMainCategoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainCategoryName);
            viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbMainCategory);
            viewHolderParent.ivCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCategory);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolderParent);
        } else {
            viewHolderParent = (ViewHolderParent) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (parentItems.get(groupPosition).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED).equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {
            viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setChecked(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setChecked(false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (viewHolderParent.cbMainCategory.isChecked()) {
                    parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < childItems.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                        childItems.get(groupPosition).get(i).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                else {
                    parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < childItems.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                        childItems.get(groupPosition).get(i).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;
        ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;

        viewHolderParent.tvMainCategoryName.setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, final boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolderChild viewHolderChild;
        child = childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_layout_choose_category, null);
            viewHolderChild = new ViewHolderChild();

            viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryImage);
            viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryName);
            viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSubCategory);
            viewHolderChild.viewDivider = convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewDivider);
            viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryPrice);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolderChild);
        } else {
            viewHolderChild = (ViewHolderChild) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED).equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {
            viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setChecked(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setChecked(false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryName.setText(child.get(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_NAME));
        viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryPrice.setText(child.get(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_PRICE));
        Picasso.get().load(child.get(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_IMAGE)).fit().into(viewHolderChild.tvSubCategoryImage);
//        Picasso.get().load()
//        viewHolderChild.value.setText(child.get());

        viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (viewHolderChild.cbSubCategory.isChecked()) {
                    count = 0;
                    childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                    childItems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < childItems.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                    if (childItems.get(groupPosition).get(i).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED).equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (count == childItems.get(groupPosition).size()) {
                    parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    parentItems.get(groupPosition).put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;
                ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    private class ViewHolderParent {

        TextView tvMainCategoryName;
        CheckBox cbMainCategory;
        ImageView ivCategory;
    }

    private class ViewHolderChild {

        ImageView tvSubCategoryImage;
        TextView tvSubCategoryName;
        CheckBox cbSubCategory;
        View viewDivider;
        TextView tvSubCategoryPrice;
    }


}
```

**This is my Data value include soruce TabFragment1 **

```
            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                jobj = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    //서버 연결
                    Url = new URL(strUrl);  // URL화 한다.
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection(); // URL을 연결한 객체 생성.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); // post방식 통신
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);       // 쓰기모드 지정
                    conn.setDoInput(true);        // 읽기모드 지정

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; utf-8");
                    conn.connect();


                    //데이터 전달 하는곳

                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                    wr.write(etp_cd);

                    wr.flush();

                    wr.close(); //전달후 닫아준다.


                    // 데이터 받아오는 곳
                    InputStream is = null;        //input스트림 개방
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));  //문자열 셋 세팅
                    StringBuffer rbuffer = new StringBuffer();   //문자열을 담기 위한 객체
                    String line = null;

                    rbuffer.append(reader.readLine());

                    jobj = new JSONObject(rbuffer.toString().trim());
                    is.close();
//                    result = rbuffer.toString().trim();
                    conn.disconnect();


                    Log.e("result", jobj+"");


                } catch (MalformedURLException | ProtocolException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    io.printStackTrace();
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return jobj;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


//                Log.e("넘어왓는지 확인", jobj + "");


//

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jobj.get("result");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        if(i==0) {
                            String pd_nm;
                            String pd_img;
                            String pd_content;
                            String pd_price;
                            JSONArray sarray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("수의");
                            for (int s=0; s<sarray.length(); s++) {
                                JSONObject sjobj =  sarray.getJSONObject(s);
                                pd_nm = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_nm");
                                pd_img = sjobj.getString("etp_img_path");
                                pd_content = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_content");
                                pd_price = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_price");
                                Log.e("수의 imageURL",pd_img);

                                f_s.add(new SubCategoryItem(pd_nm,pd_img,pd_content,pd_price)); //array 배열에 넣음
                            }


                        } else if(i==1){

                            String pd_nm;
                            String pd_img;
                            String pd_content;
                            String pd_price;
                            JSONArray sarray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("함");
                            //                            Log.e("sarray",sarray+"");
                            for (int s=0; s<sarray.length(); s++) {
                                JSONObject sjobj =  sarray.getJSONObject(s);
                                pd_nm = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_nm");
                                pd_img = sjobj.getString("etp_img_path");
                                pd_content = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_content");
                                pd_price = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_price");

//                                            Log.e("수의",pd_nm + "//" + pd_price);

                                f_h.add(new SubCategoryItem(pd_nm,pd_img,pd_content,pd_price)); //함 배열 add
                            }
                        } else if(i==2){

                            String pd_nm;
                            String pd_img;
                            String pd_content;
                            String pd_price;
                            JSONArray sarray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("관");

                            for (int s=0; s<sarray.length(); s++) {
                                JSONObject sjobj =  sarray.getJSONObject(s);
                                pd_nm = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_nm");
                                pd_img = sjobj.getString("etp_img_path");
                                pd_content = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_content");
                                pd_price = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_price");


                                f_g.add(new SubCategoryItem(pd_nm,pd_img,pd_content,pd_price)); //관 배열 add
                            }
                        } else {

                            String pd_nm;
                            String pd_img;
                            String pd_content;
                            String pd_price;

                            JSONArray farray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("화장");
                            for (int f=0; f<farray.length(); f++) {
                                JSONObject sjobj =  farray.getJSONObject(f);
                                pd_nm = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_nm");
                                pd_img = sjobj.getString("etp_img_path");
                                pd_content = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_content");
                                pd_price = sjobj.getString("etp_pd_price");

                                //                                Log.e("수의",pd_nm + "//" + pd_price);
                                //해당 모델 객체에 add하기
                                f_f.add(new SubCategoryItem(pd_nm,pd_img,pd_content,pd_price));
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    setupReferences(view,f_s,f_h,f_g,f_f);

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.execute();


        btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GoodbyepetReservationResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    private void setupReferences(View view, ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> f_s, ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> f_h, ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> f_g, ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> f_f) {

        lvCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.lvCategory);
        arCategory = new ArrayList<>(); // 큰 상품들의 array 배열

        arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        parentItems = new ArrayList<>();
        childItems = new ArrayList<>();


        Log.e("넘어온 이미지",f_s.get(0).getPd_img()+"");
//        ArrayList<SubCategoryItem> list = suit;

        // 1
        DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();
        dataItem.setCategoryId("1");
        dataItem.setCategoryName("수의");
//        arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <f_s.size(); i++) {
            SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
            subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(i));
            subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
            subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName(f_s.get(i).getPd_nm());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_price(f_s.get(i).getPd_price());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_img(f_s.get(i).getPd_img());
            arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
        }
        dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
        arCategory.add(dataItem);



        // 2
        dataItem = new DataItem();
        dataItem.setCategoryId("2");
        dataItem.setCategoryName("함");
        arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < f_h.size(); j++) {

            SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
            subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(j));
            subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
            subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName(f_h.get(j).getPd_nm());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_price(f_h.get(j).getPd_price());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_img(f_h.get(j).getPd_img());
            arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
        }
        dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
        arCategory.add(dataItem);


        // 3
        dataItem = new DataItem();
        dataItem.setCategoryId("3");
        dataItem.setCategoryName("관");
        arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int k = 0; k < f_g.size(); k++) {

            SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
            subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(k));
            subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
            subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName(f_g.get(k).getPd_nm());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_price(f_g.get(k).getPd_price());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_img(f_g.get(k).getPd_img());
            arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
        }
        dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
        arCategory.add(dataItem);



        //4
        dataItem = new DataItem();
        dataItem.setCategoryId("4");
        dataItem.setCategoryName("화장비");
        arSubCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int o = 0; o < f_f.size(); o++) {

            SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem = new SubCategoryItem();
            subCategoryItem.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(o));
            subCategoryItem.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
            subCategoryItem.setSubCategoryName(f_f.get(o).getPd_nm());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_img(f_f.get(o).getPd_img());
            subCategoryItem.setPd_price(f_f.get(o).getPd_price());
            arSubCategory.add(subCategoryItem);
        }

        dataItem.setSubCategory(arSubCategory);
        arCategory.add(dataItem);




        Log.d("TAG", "setupReferences: " + arCategory.size());

        for (DataItem data : arCategory) {
//                        Log.i("Item id",item.id);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> childArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> mapParent = new HashMap<String, String>();

            mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_ID, data.getCategoryId());
            mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_NAME, data.getCategoryName());

            int countIsChecked = 0;
            for (SubCategoryItem subCategoryItem : data.getSubCategory()) {

                HashMap<String, String> mapChild = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_ID, subCategoryItem.getSubId());
                mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_NAME, subCategoryItem.getSubCategoryName());
                mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_PRICE, subCategoryItem.getPd_price());
                mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.SUB_CATEGORY_IMAGE, subCategoryItem.getPd_img());
                mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.CATEGORY_ID, subCategoryItem.getCategoryId());
                mapChild.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, subCategoryItem.getIsChecked());

                if (subCategoryItem.getIsChecked()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE)) {

                    countIsChecked++;
                }
                childArrayList.add(mapChild);
            }

            if (countIsChecked == data.getSubCategory().size()) {

                data.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_TRUE);
            } else {
                data.setIsChecked(ConstantManager.CHECK_BOX_CHECKED_FALSE);
            }

            mapParent.put(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED, data.getIsChecked());
            childItems.add(childArrayList);
            parentItems.add(mapParent);

        }

        ConstantManager.parentItems = parentItems;
        ConstantManager.childItems = childItems;

        myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter = new MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), parentItems, childItems, false);
        lvCategory.setAdapter(myCategoriesExpandableListAdapter);
    }
```

What i want result is 
send to the child data from category that i only checked

Comment: What do you get when logging `String isChecked = MyCategoriesExpandableListAdapter.parentItems.get(i).get(ConstantManager.Parameter.IS_CHECKED);`?

Comment: Ooops ! i didnt attach my fragment ... i edit sorry..